# how to convert json/array from ajax responseText in to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have used ajax in the code which works perfectly and give me json or array which ever I want as an output.
the code I have used is,

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://map_ajax_control.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();

var test = xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(test);
```

This test variable gives me json/array.

I want to get the data which I received in the test variable in the JavaScript array.

The question is, how can I decode json data in javascript array?
I have used the code as,

```
var output = new Array();  
output = json_decode(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

but this code is not giving me any output.
How can I do this two things?

Comment: Weighing down a web app with the entire jQuery library would be overkill if all this requires is logic for a json ajax handler

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.Split(',');
```

If it does not solve your problem then in your php code, use simple `json_encode(your array);` and on javascript, use `myData= eval("(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")");` .

I suggest you to follow this approach:

Encode the data you want to send by using a [PHP binding for JSON](http://in.php.net/json) at the server and decode the same using [Javascript library for JSON](http://json.org/js.html). 
as:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

or

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);
```

Note: Include json2 javascript file to your solution..

[Problem with storing values in Array from php to AJAX](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/244300)

Comment: Absolutely!  I was getting a responseText object instead of a simple type.  Using this approach ( and knowing a little about the object), I can extract the field **d** which is the boolean I cared about in this case.

Comment: WTH, PLEASE do not use the `eval` option of decoding the json, it is a blatant xss vulnerability

Answer (score 31):

Most browsers support [JSON.parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Its usage is simple:

```
obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
alert(obj.length);
```

For the browsers that don't you can implement it using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: i have used this also.But its not working.It is not giving me any output

Answer (score 2):

json is nothing but javascript object notation.
You just need to parse it as suggested by Sudhir.
You can also use jQuery.parseJSON for it.

And to do ajax, I strongly suggest you to use some library, preferably jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/